# Can't import own python module in Postgresql plpython function

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, docker

I created my own python module and packaged it with distutils. Now I installed it on a new system (python setup.py install) and I'm trying to call it from a plpython3u function, but I get an error saying the module does not exist.

It was working on a previous Ubuntu instalation, and I'm not sure what I did wrong when setting up my new system.

I'm trying this on a Ubuntu 15.10 pc with postgresql 9.5, everything freshly installed. I'm also trying this setup in a docker image built with the same componentes (ubuntu 15.10 and pg 9.5). I get the same error in both setups.

Could you please hint me about why this is failing? I wrote down my installation instructions for both systems (native and docker), so I can provide them if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Did you install the module system wide using sudo? Or are you using virtual env?

Comment: Hi Noorul, yes I did use sudo. I tried without using sudo and got a permission error.

Comment: I executed echo $PYTHONPATH in a terminal and it's empty, nevertheless I tried importing the same module from an interactive python sesion and it works fine. It seems like it's a problem with my postgres/plpython setup. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same python interpreter? How are you running the script? If it is executable, see the shebang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys I think I found the problem. I'm using plpython3 in my stored procedure, but intalled my custom module using python 2. I just did sudo python3 setup.py install and now it's working on the native Ubuntu. I'll now try modifying my docker image and see if it works there too.
Thanks

Comment: You should mark this answer as correct so that it won't come up in search results as having no answer.

Comment: I'll do that as soon as SO allows me to (it says I have to wait 2 days before accepting my own answer).